# Как разбить строку несколько раз в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, список

Допустим, у меня есть строка:    `message = "Лебедьракщука"`

Вместе с этим у меня есть ключ, указывающий на количество символов до каждого пробела:    `key = 634`

Как мне создать список:    `finally = ['Лебедь', 'рак', 'щука']`

Comment: Почему ключ в таком странном формате?

Comment: Не сразу понял, что 634 это `[6, 3, 4]` символа.

Comment: @NickVolynkin если бы не твой комментарий, я бы скипнул вопрос :)

Answer (score 4):

К примеру так:

```
In [27]: message
Out[27]: 'Лебедьракщука'

In [28]: key
Out[28]: [6, 3, 4]

In [29]: def splitWords(word, key):
    ...:     step = 0
    ...:     result = []
    ...:     for i in key:
    ...:         result.append(word[step:i+step])
    ...:         step += i
    ...:     return result
    ...:

In [30]: splitWords(message, key)
Out[30]: ['Лебедь', 'рак', 'щука']
```

---

По поводу `key`:

Если он в таком формате, делаем так:

```
In [1]: key = 634

In [2]: list(map(int, str(key)))
Out[2]: [6, 3, 4]
```

Comment: result.append(word[step:i+step])
TypeError: must be str, not int
Выдает это

Comment: @ТимофейПанфилий обновил ответ

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться RegEx:

```
In [62]: key = 634

In [63]: key = list(map(int, str(key)))

In [64]: key
Out[64]: [6, 3, 4]
```

---

```
import re

In [22]: pat = ''.join(['(.{{{}}})'.format(k) for k in key])

In [23]: repl = ' '.join([r'\{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(key)+1)])

In [24]: pat
Out[24]: '(.{6})(.{3})(.{4})'

In [25]: repl
Out[25]: '\\1 \\2 \\3'

In [26]: re.sub(pat, repl, message)
Out[26]: 'Лебедь рак щука'

In [27]: re.sub(pat, repl, message).split()
Out[27]: ['Лебедь', 'рак', 'щука']
```

PS но решение от @Alban мне нравится больше...

---

Вот еще одно решение:

```
In [57]: [message[sum(key[:i]) : sum(key[:i+1])] for i in range(len(key))]
Out[57]: ['Лебедь', 'рак', 'щука']
```

Как это работает:

```
In [73]: [print('{} : {}'.format(sum(key[:i]),sum(key[:i+1]))) for i in range(len(key))]
0 : 6
6 : 9
9 : 13
```

Comment: А мне вот Ваше больше по нраву. Впечатляет  :)

Comment: @Alban, ваше решение понятнее, эффективнее и проще - решение с RegEx проигрывает по всем показателям... ;)

Comment: Мне просто на ум не приходило даже что-то подобное. Но да, красота в простом)